# Story about a man who is perpetually cloned and imprisoned as punishment for a crime

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

When I was in middle school, I read a short story about a man who was told he was teleported to this other place. I don't remember if it was another planet, or if it was a ship, or what, but he was there to help with something. He couldn't remember anything when he woke up from his "teleportation" but it slowly came back to him. I think he had a wife and a kid, but I'm not sure.

From the moment he wakes up, he hears Mozart, but it's completely in his head. It doesn't go away. There are these... orb things that take care of him, not actual people. Again, I think. It has been a while since I read it.

When he recovers a little bit more, he finds out that he was actually cloned, and that he had been cloned many, many times. I think it was a repayment for a crime he committed against the orbs (who may have originally been people). He finds out that it is actually something like a hundred years after he originally lived and his family is all dead. He is then escorted to a white jail cell.

That's all I really remember. I'm sorry this is so sketchy, but I honestly can't remember any other details of the story.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.